# Sencha Touch grouping list on button click

Tags: list, grouping, sencha-touch

I'm new to Sencha Touch and the Ext JS logic. Actually, I'm displaying a list of items containing two fields (title, type) grouped by default alphabetically by first character of the title and I added a button to a toolbar that I want it to switch the grouping to be by type. I tried to programmatically set the getGroupString function in the buton handler in this way :

```
var toolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
  dock: 'top',
  title: 'Toolbar',
  items: [{
    text: 'By type',
    handler: function() {
      MyApp.MyStore.getGroupString = function(record) {
        return record.get('type');
      };
      MyApp.itemsList.update();

    }
  }]
});
```

But that seems just to not work. Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: Actually I have resolved it, just needed to call refresh() on the list instead of update()
`MyApp.itemsList.refresh();`

Comment: Hey Nacef, glad you solved it, on SO it's acceptable to answer your own question and accept it, thus closing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to close the question as I have already answered it
    MyApp.itemsList.refresh();